How can I record internal computer sound joined with input sound and save all in one file?
I want to write a client and server in c#, client will record internal sound + input sound (microphone) and stream it to the server, how can I achieve the join effect, to stream their both without any sound problems and strange sounds.
I'm expecting a client program and a server program, client will record the internal sound for example Spotify music and will record the microphone input. Than the client program will join those and stream the result to the server and the server will here that.

The easiest way to achieve this is to first get a program like VirtualAudioCable that does a loopback, allowing you to stream the output of your computer into an input.
Then use two NAudio WaveIn joined into a MixingSampleProvider to get your final stream. I would say that a NAudio component to stream to an IceCast server for example would be the easiest way to achieve it.
